# Computing 3-term Connection Coefficients for Wavelets

Tags: python, wavelet

I am trying to calculate the three-term connection coefficients

$$
Λ_{l,m}^{d_1,d_2,d_3} = ∫_{-∞}^∞ φ^{(d_1)}(x) φ^{(d_2)}_l(x) φ^{(d_3)}_m(x) dx
$$

for Daubechies wavelets numerically using Python. [This report (p. 20)](https://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2004/rapporter04/besora_jordi_04091.pdf) gives a nice overview of how to calculate them.

I wrote a [(well documented) implementation](https://manuels.github.io/db_cc3/docs/cc3_2.html) in python and for the two-term connection coefficients had no problems but when I compare my 3-term results with the ones of Resnikoff and Wells (1998) I find lots of errors (only the (l=m) coefficients appear to be correct).

I am starring at the code for weeks now, but I cannot find any errors. I would be very pleased if somebody would give me a hint where the error might be.